# Parse Push Notification from PHP API not registering in parse.com dashboard as "opened"

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

When are using the `Parse` PHP API to send `Push Notifications` to our users on `iOS`. But, for some reason we are not registering any "Push Opens" for any of our users. Here is the `PHP` code we are using:

```
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("user_id", $user_id);
$pushResponse = ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "push_time" => $push_time,
  "expiration_interval" => $expiration_interval,
  "data" => array(
    "alert" => $alert,
    "badge" => 1,
    "ota" => : array(
        "type" => 2,
     )
));
```

[image]

In iOS I am making sure to handle the notifications:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
        [self processNotification:userInfo];
    }
}
```

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
    BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
    BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    }
}
```

Is there something that I have missed that would let `Parse` know that a specific user opened the Push Notification?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of users you have: it is not unlikely that users don't open the app by means of the push notification. Many users, upon receiving a notification, either ignore it or open the app by touching the app icon on the home screen.

You should send a notification to a test device and make sure to open the app using the notification. Then you could check if Parse tracks the app open correctly.